# ORA-00905: missing keyword when trying to create a synonym

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer, oracle-9i

I have a problem when I try to create a synonym like this:

```
CREATE SYNONYM B2H.BILLING_USER_ACTIVITY@PACOMNET 
 FOR B2H.BILLING_USER_ACTIVITY@PACOMNET.US.ORACLE.COM;
```

Why does this happen and how can I correct it?

Comment: As the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7001.htm) says, you can create sysnonyms in the current DB only.  So the first `@PACOMNET` in the sysnonym name is unnecessary (and causing the error).

Comment: As an aside, you should probably sort your DB link names and sqlnet config out too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7001.htm) says implicitly, you can create synonyms in the current DB only. So the first `@PACOMNET` in the synonym name is unnecessary (and causing the error). You should instead connect to the `PACOMNET` database and run

```
CREATE SYNONYM B2H.BILLING_USER_ACTIVITY
FOR B2H.BILLING_USER_ACTIVITY@PACOMNET.US.ORACLE.COM;
```

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, [DDL on remote database is not permitted](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:597877500346143250). One likely reason is that a distributed transaction commit can not be initiated at the remote site (you can't `COMMIT@remote`) and since DDL statements include a commit they are not permitted.

You would get an `ORA-02021` with other DDL statements:

> DDL operations are not allowed on a remote database

You can create the database link by connecting directly to the remote database.

As suggested in the askTom discussion, you can also use `DBMS_JOB@remote` or `DBMS_SCHEDULER@remote` to create a distinct remote transaction that can initiate the DDL statement.

Answer (score 1):

if one enters the statement in sqlplus (Oracle10.2, Solaris 5.10) I get the following is displayed:

```
SQL> CREATE SYNONYM BILLING_USER_ACTIVITY@PACOMNET 
  2   FOR B2H.BILLING_USER_ACTIVITY@PACOMNET.US.ORACLE.COM;
CREATE SYNONYM BILLING_USER_ACTIVITY@PACOMNET
                                    *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00905: missing keyword
```

After the statement the failing line is printed and below the failing line an asteriks (*) marks the character where the sql parser has located the problem. So the problem is located at the '@' character. The syntax diagram of the 'create synonym' statement can be found in the [manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_7001.htm#CJAJCDDF)

```
CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] [ PUBLIC ] SYNONYM
   [ schema. ] synonym
   FOR [ schema. ] object [ @ dblink ] ;
```

In contrast to the object specification after the 'FOR' the synonym specification before the for does not contain a '@dblinK'.

For syntax problems you should use an appropriate tool (e.g. sqlplus) that displays the exact position of the error where the statement fails.