# Factoring out subselect (with clause) ends in ORA-00904

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I am trying fo factor a repetitive subquery with `with` but getting `ORA-00904` over and over again.

This is my base query which works quite well:

```
select tka.id, tka.name, txt.text as langname, einh.text as einheit, tka.typ,
  vgd.a_wert, vgd.i_wert, vgd.r_wert, vgd.d_wert, vgd.quelle
from vgd vgd
  inner join vgs vgs on
    vgd.vgs_id = vgs.id and vgs.schluessel = ?
  inner join tka tka on tka.id = vgd.tka_id
  left join (select txt0.* from txt txt0, spr spr
               where txt0.spr_id = spr.id and spr.name = ?) txt on tka.txt_id_langname = txt.id
  left join (select einh0.* from txt einh0, spr spr
               where einh0.spr_id = spr.id and spr.name = ?) einh on tka.txt_id_einheit = einh.id
  inner join mtdb mtdb on tka.name = mtdb.tedabattribut
               and mtdb.tedabattribut is not null and mtdb.baugruppe = ?
  where tka.status = 2
    and tka.felddimension = 0
    and not exists (select 1 from vgd vgd2
                      where vgd2.vgs_id = vgd.vgs_id
                        and vgd2.tka_id = vgd.tka_id
                        and vgd2.ai_id > vgd.ai_id);
```

Now as you can see, I have to pass the value to  `spr.name` twice. I would like to avoid that. The query has been transformed to this for starters
*EDIT* The query has been rewritten to ANSI style as Leigh Riffel wrote but still no avail.

```
with spr0 as (select id from spr where name = ?)
select tka.id, tka.name, txt.text as langname, einh.text as einheit, tka.typ,
  vgd.a_wert, vgd.i_wert, vgd.r_wert, vgd.d_wert, vgd.quelle
from vgd vgd
  cross join spr0 spr
  inner join vgs vgs on
    vgd.vgs_id = vgs.id and vgs.schluessel = ?
  inner join tka tka on tka.id = vgd.tka_id
  left join (select txt0.* from txt txt0
               where txt0.spr_id = spr.id) txt on tka.txt_id_langname = txt.id
  left join (select einh0.* from txt einh0
               where einh0.spr_id = spr.id) einh on tka.txt_id_einheit = einh.id
  inner join mtdb mtdb on tka.name = mtdb.tedabattribut
               and mtdb.tedabattribut is not null and mtdb.baugruppe = ?
  where tka.status = 2
    and tka.felddimension = 0
    and not exists (select 1 from vgd vgd2
                      where vgd2.vgs_id = vgd.vgs_id
                        and vgd2.tka_id = vgd.tka_id
                        and vgd2.ai_id > vgd.ai_id);
```

But SQL Developer is still giving me

```
ORA-00904: "SPR"."ID": ungültiger Bezeichner
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

Table names have been shortened for brevity.

*EDIT 2*: I have followed miracle173's advice, reduced the query to a mininum and ran with `SQL*Plus`. Here is the output:

```
select spr.*, txt.*, vgd.*
from vgd vgd
  cross join spr spr
  inner join tka tka on tka.id = vgd.tka_id
  left join (select txt0.* from txt txt0
               where txt0.spr_id = spr.id) txt on tka.txt_id_langname = txt.id
  where vgd.vgs_id = 32 and spr.name = 'de';

FEHLER in Zeile 6:
ORA-00904: "SPR"."ID": ungültiger Bezeichner
```

The error is in line 6. So there must be some issue with the cross join and the alias.

Is anyone able to spot the missing link? Where is the flaw in my idea?

**Solution**: Thanks for Leigh's tip to outfactor table `spr` I have a working solution now:

```
select tka.id, tka.name, txt.text as langname, einh.text as einheit,
  mtdb.camosmerkmal as merkmal, tka.typ, vgd.a_wert, vgd.i_wert,
  vgd.r_wert, vgd.d_wert, vgd.quelle
from vgd vgd
  cross join spr spr
  inner join vgs vgs on
    vgd.vgs_id = vgs.id and vgs.schluessel = ?
  inner join tka tka on tka.id = vgd.tka_id and tka.status = 2 
                        and tka.felddimension = 0
  left join txt txt on tka.txt_id_langname = txt.id and txt.spr_id = spr.id
  left join txt einh on tka.txt_id_einheit = einh.id and einh.spr_id = spr.id
  inner join mtdb mtdb on tka.name = mtdb.tedabattribut
               and mtdb.tedabattribut is not null and mtdb.baugruppe = ?
  where spr.name = ?
    and not exists (select 1 from vgd vgd2
                      where vgd2.vgs_id = vgd.vgs_id
                        and vgd2.tka_id = vgd.tka_id
                        and vgd2.ai_id > vgd.ai_id);
```

Comment: The problem is in `SELECT txt0.* FROM txt txt0 WHERE txt0.spr_id = spr0.id` where there is no `spr0` in the FROM clause.  If you check Leigh's answer carefully, there is a line `CROSS JOIN spr0` whixh is missing from your version.

Comment: @dezso, shame on me. I pasted the wrong query. Now the correct query is in the question but the problem still remains.

Comment: I think those subselects are unnecessary complications only (could be solved with simply joining those txt tables as you select * from them), but at the moment I don't have the time for proving it.

Comment: Where does the error occurr in your query? I wrote an answer that shows [how to find this when using sqlplus](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28538/ora-00905-missing-keyword-when-trying-to-create-a-synonym/28570#28570). But more important: can you simplify the query and reproduce the error anyway? Simplifying means: remove joins from the where clause, remove expressions from the were-clause (or the whole were-clause if possible), remove fields from the select-list.

Comment: @miracle173, please see my edit above. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be an issue with the mixture of ANSI and Oracle style joins as well as the referencing of a cross joined table in a subquery.  Converting/removing these constructs, you should end up with something like this:

```
WITH spr0 AS (
      SELECT id FROM tka WHERE name = ?
   )
SELECT tka.id, tka.name, txt.text AS langname, einh.text AS einheit, tka.typ, vgd.a_wert,
   vgd.i_wert, vgd.r_wert, vgd.d_wert, vgd.quelle
FROM vgd vgd
CROSS JOIN spr0
JOIN vgs ON vgd.vgs_id = vgs.id AND vgs.schluessel = ?
JOIN tka tka ON tka.id = vgd.tka_id
   AND tka.txt_id_einheit = einh.id
JOIN mtdb mtdb ON tka.name = mtdb.tedabattribut 
   AND mtdb.tedabattribut IS NOT NULL 
   AND mtdb.baugruppe = ?
LEFT JOIN txt ON txt.spr_id = spr0.id ON tka.txt_id_langname = txt.id
LEFT JOIN txt einh ON einh0.spr_id = spr.id AND spr.name = ? 
WHERE tka.status = 2 AND tka.felddimension = 0 
AND NOT EXISTS
   (
      SELECT 1 FROM vgd vgd2
      WHERE vgd2.vgs_id = vgd.vgs_id AND vgd2.tka_id = vgd.tka_id AND vgd2.ai_id > vgd.ai_id
   );
```

Comment: Hi Leigh, thanks for your feedback. What problem poses the mising of styles?
I have rewritten the query but still getting the same error message. Se my edit of the question.

Comment: Follow miracle173's instructions in the comment above to diagnose further.  There aren't any different columns, so there must be something more complex going on.

Comment: Done, see question edit!

Comment: Does it work if you move `txt0.spr_id = spr.id` out of the subquery and into the `ON` clause as `txt.spr_id = spr.id`?

Comment: Leigh, you are a genius. That did the trick. See edit please and adapt your answer, I will accept it then.

Answer (score 3):

For analyzing your problem your query

```
select spr.*, txt.*, vgd.*
from vgd vgd
  cross join spr spr
  inner join tka tka on tka.id = vgd.tka_id
  left join (select txt0.* from txt txt0
    where txt0.spr_id = spr.id) txt on tka.txt_id_langname = txt.id
  where vgd.vgs_id = 32 and spr.name = 'de';
```

can be simplified further

```
select *
from vgd vgd
  cross join spr spr
  inner join tka tka on tka.id = vgd.tka_id
  left join (select txt0.* from txt txt0
    where txt0.spr_id = spr.id) txt on tka.txt_id_langname = txt.id
```

and further

```
select *
from spr spr
  left join (select txt0.* from txt txt0
    where txt0.spr_id = spr.id) txt
```

and I think the error will occurr again.

The [join syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#CHDIJFDJ) is something like

```
 query_table_expression1 alias1 JOIN query_table_expression2 ON condition
```

*alias1* is known in *condition* but not in *query_table_expression2*. For me it is not clear what the *join (select...* clause should do. Perhaps you are mixing up different join styles ( I borrow *styles* from Leigh Riffel, because I did not know the plural of syntax :-) and you want express something like

```
select *
from spr, txt 
where txt.spr_id = spr.id
```

which is the same as

```
select *
from spr join txt 
on txt.spr_id = spr.id
```

I avoid to use alias names that are equal to the name of the table that they are aliasing. because it does not make sense to me.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis. Leigh's last tip made it work. Concerning your last remark. I have shortened the table names for the sake of brevity.

Comment: meanwhile if found [syntaxes](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/syntax#Noun)